# android Firebase display all data based on category chosen

Tags: android, firebase

In my project I want the user to be able to click on a category of their choosing, once clicked it will bring them to a page and they will see all the post that belongs to that category they chose. For example if they choose love for their category then it will show all the post that belongs to the love category. I was trying out this code that I thought of but I don't think its the correct way to do it. I did run my code and I didn't get any errors but I didn't get any results either. I'm  pretty lost here. Can someone help me? I will show you my code Thanks in advance

databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");

```
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    intent1.getStringExtra("name");
    String c=intent1.toString();
    
     databaseReference.equalTo(c).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            myUploads.clear();
            DialogUtil.closeProgressDialog();

            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Model_Information upload=postsnapshot.getValue(Model_Information.class);
                    myUploads.add(upload);
                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                }
            }
            linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            DialogUtil.closeProgressDialog();
            linearLayoutWithoutItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(Explore_For_Categories.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

//This is the firebase json

{
  "Posts" : {
    "2WO5Gyk17LTzoifYdDBnBFmzYOV2" : {
      "-MThtE88y20_skyy0kk3" : {
        
        "category" : "love",
        "clicks" : 0,
        "created" : "2-17-2021",
        "body" : "Love is powerful",
        "id" : "-MThtE88y20_skyy0kk3",
        "mImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flute-43191.appspot.com/o/.jpg?alt=media&token=2efcc398-d299-460c-9a16-4bf2e10d36f4",
        "main_id" : "-MThtE88y20_skyy0kk3",
        "time" : "10:49 AM",
        "timestamp" : 1613530198742,
        "views" : 0,
        
      }
```

Comment: Are you able to get results for the category "love" from the firebase?

Comment: @akhilnair no I get no results

Comment: I guess you need to check how the posts with "love" is related in the firebase. May be its via "main_id".

Comment: yes but how do I get from Main_id

Comment: your code is missing many lines please post the complete code , like the databaseRefernce initialization

Comment: @BilalRammal I edited my question and added the databaseRefernce intialization. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here, Try this

```
Intent intent1 = getIntent();
String c = intent1.getStringExtra("name");
```

Then pass it to firebase param

```
databaseReference.equalTo(c).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){}
```

add one after the intent to check that intent not null:

**EDIT**:

```
Intent intent1 = getIntent(); 
String c = intent1.getStringExtra("name"); 
Log.d(TAG, "EXTRA_STRING = " + c);
```

another one after onDataChanged()

```
@Override public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange"); 
... }
```

now add item on firebase and trace if you got intent as well if listener occurred on your reference

Comment: try to add log statements to trace the error